# Java send email: smtp.gmail.com error

Tags: java, gmail

I have the following java code to send email:

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
{
return new PasswordAuthentication("erjobertolazo@gmail.com", "mypassword");
}
});

try {

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("erjobertolazo@gmail.com"));

Address[] toUser = InternetAddress 
.parse("Recipient1@gmail.com, Recipient2@hotmail.com, Recipient3@yahoo.com.br");  
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toUser);
message.setSubject("TEST SEND EMAIL");//Assunto
message.setText("THIS IS JUST A TEST!");

Transport.send(message);
```

I get the following error message:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: your controller raised an exception
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:103) root cause
>
> org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the
>   following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465
>       org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1410)
>       org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1437)
>       br.com.corpcontrol.controller.UsuariosController.testeEmailB(UsuariosController.java:245)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExecuteMethodInterceptor.intercept(ExecuteMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:61)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.InstantiateInterceptor.intercept(InstantiateInterceptor.java:48)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionHandlerInterceptor.java:67)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.FlashInterceptor.intercept(FlashInterceptor.java:83)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.LazyInterceptorHandler.execute(LazyInterceptorHandler.java:61)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.interceptor.ResourceLookupInterceptor.intercept(ResourceLookupInterceptor.java:69)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.execute(ToInstantiateInterceptorHandler.java:56)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.DefaultInterceptorStack.next(DefaultInterceptorStack.java:54)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.core.EnhancedRequestExecution.execute(EnhancedRequestExecution.java:44)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor$1.insideRequest(VRaptor.java:93)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.spring.SpringProvider.provideForRequest(SpringProvider.java:58)
>       br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.doFilter(VRaptor.java:99) root cause

Somebody knows how i can do that? 
Can be with other email server. Thanks for advice!

Comment: can you please provide more detailed stack-trace of exception, to understand what's going on?

Comment: @YaroslavBoichuk, i edited the question, now have the full stack-trace of exception.

Comment: Have you allowed less secured apps to access your gmail account?
https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: @EduwHS , No, i haven't did that, i will try now! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ensure that you don't have enabled "*Two factor authentication*"
2. Navigate to: "https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1" and turn on "*Access for less secure apps*"